# Wanted to make it 2 rows & 2 columns but end up getting weird response

Tags: ios, iphone

```html
   <tr id="section-6465178" class="section loyalty">

  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" role="presentation">
<!-- Button : BEGIN -->

<header style="padding: 30px;
  text-align: center; font-size: 35px;"> <span style="color: #8c734b; font-size: 20px; font-family: Lora;">More on the friends of Bynd(FOB) Loyalty Programme</span></header>


<section class="col-1-2">
  <th class="earn points" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-radius: 1px; padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 200px;"><img src="https://cdn.abc.com/files/Earn_Points_v2.png?v=1661306144" style="width: 50px; height: 50px ;" />
    <p>Earn Points</p>
    <p> Collect 1 point for every S$1 spent online</p>
</section>
</th>
<th class="get rewarded" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-radius: 1px; padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 200px;"><img src="https://cdn.abc.com/files/Get_Rewards.png?v=1661306273" style="width: 50px; height: 50px ;" />
  <p>Get Rewarded</p>
  <p> Enjoy special rewards by redeeming your accumulated FOB points</p>
</th>
<section class="col-1-2">
  <th class="early access" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-radius: 1px; padding-left: 300px; padding-right: 0px;"><img src="https://cdn.abc.com/files/Early_Access_v2.png?v=1661306185" style="width: 50px; height: 50px ;" />
    <p>Early Access</p>
    <p>Get early access to new product launches and sales promotions.</p>
  </th>
</section>

<section class="col-1-2">
  <th class="tier benefits" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-radius: 1px; padding-left: 300px; padding-right: 0px;"><img src="https://cdn.abc.com/files/Exclusive_Benefits_v2.png?v=1661306185" style="width: 50px; height: 50px ;" />
    <p>Tier Benefits</p>
    <p>Advance to next tier for more benefits and discounts.</p>
  </th>
</section>
  </table>
  </th>
</tr>
```

I wanted to make it 2 rows 2 columns but seems like it has a conflict. Previously, I've tried div tags but couldn't work too.

result:
[image: result]

Comment: I'm not sure what '2 rows 2 columns' should look like to you, do you want the icons to be in a vertical column? But they are bending to the right? Also, why is the entire table inside a table row (`tr`)?

Comment: to be in a horizontal column , i created table just cause it could not fit in it.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Bman70/7d4rf15b/

Comment: The early access & tier benefits component should be below the "earn points and get rewarded" :) also, from my code, i cannot input css as this code is coming from a former developer so i can only input html and style tag

Comment: ok you probably just need two table rows, each one having two components

Comment: yea unfortunately i tried doing that but seems to keep giving conflict errors

Comment: i change the link and the layout seems to work by adding two `<tr>`, but probably needs more styling. The inline css seems to be possibly problematic.

Comment: Alright thanks man, sorry what link are you talking about? *edited

Comment: i posted it in an answer

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Comment: Please don't make photographs of your screen. The quality is rather bad and important bits are cut off. Instead, simply take a screenshot next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can stack the components by adding two table rows `<tr>` - so there are two table head (`th`) elements inside each new row.

The inline CSS seems to be causing some problems too. I didn't have time to clean it all up but just moved the important parts over to a separate CSS. Still needs more styling in order to get the font sizes right and import the Lora font correctly. Of course you could get good results with just positioned `divs` too instead of tables, maybe someone will post that solution.

```css
tr, th {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
padding: 30px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 35px;
color: #8c734b;
}

header.span {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Lora;
}

th {
  mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  /* padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 200px; */
}
```

```html
<tr id="section-6465178" class="section loyalty">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" role="presentation">
    <!-- Button : BEGIN -->

    <header class="span"><span class="span">More on the friends of Bynd(FOB) Loyalty Programme</span></header>

    <section class="col-1-2">
      
      <tr>
      
      <th class="earn points"><img src="https://cdn.abc.com/files/Earn_Points_v2.png?v=1661306144" style="width: 50px; height: 50px ;" />
        <p>Earn Points</p>
        <p> Collect 1 point for every S$1 spent online</p>
   
    </th>
    </section>
  
   
    <th class="get rewarded"><img src="https://cdn.abc.com/files/Get_Rewards.png?v=1661306273" style="width: 50px; height: 50px ;" />
      <p>Get Rewarded</p>
      <p> Enjoy special rewards by redeeming your accumulated FOB points</p>
  </th>
  </tr>

    <section class="col-1-2">
    
    <tr>
      <th class="early access"><img src="https://cdn.abc.com/files/Early_Access_v2.png?v=1661306185" style="width: 50px; height: 50px ;" />
        <p>Early Access</p>
        <p>Get early access to new product launches and sales promotions.</p>
      </th>
    </section>

    <section class="col-1-2">
      <th class="tier benefits"><img src="https://cdn.abc.com/files/Exclusive_Benefits_v2.png?v=1661306185" style="width: 50px; height: 50px ;" />
        <p>Tier Benefits</p>
        <p>Advance to next tier for more benefits and discounts.</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
    
    </section>
  </table>
  </th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some errors on the structuring of the table. If you wonna create a table with 2 rows and 2 columns, here is a simple example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Company</td>
    <td>Contact</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here some mistake:

- The `<tr></tr>` should be inside the table. Probably the `<tr></tr>` was passed cause of is outside the table.
- You probably forgot a `<section></section>` tag (not sure if it was wanted)
- You have used only one `<tr></tr>` tag instead two.

Here is the solution code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" role="presentation">
          <!-- Button : BEGIN -->
      
        <header style="padding: 30px;
        text-align: center; font-size: 35px;"> <span style="color: #8c734b; font-size: 20px; font-family: Lora;">More on the friends of Bynd(FOB) Loyalty Programme</span></header>
      
        <tr id="section-6465178" class="section loyalty">
            <section class="col-1-2">
                <th class="earn points" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-radius: 1px; padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 200px;"><img src="https://cdn.abc.com/files/Earn_Points_v2.png?v=1661306144" style="width: 50px; height: 50px ;" />
                    <p>Earn Points</p>
                    <p> Collect 1 point for every S$1 spent online</p>
                </th>
            </section>
            <section class="col-1-2">
                <th class="get rewarded" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-radius: 1px; padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 200px;"><img src="https://cdn.abc.com/files/Get_Rewards.png?v=1661306273" style="width: 50px; height: 50px ;" />
                    <p>Get Rewarded</p>
                    <p> Enjoy special rewards by redeeming your accumulated FOB points</p>
                </th>
            </section>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <section class="col-1-2">
                <th class="early access" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-radius: 1px; padding-left: 300px; padding-right: 0px;"><img src="https://cdn.abc.com/files/Early_Access_v2.png?v=1661306185" style="width: 50px; height: 50px ;" />
                    <p>Early Access</p>
                    <p>Get early access to new product launches and sales promotions.</p>
                </th>
            </section>
      
            <section class="col-1-2">
                <th class="tier benefits" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly; border-radius: 1px; padding-left: 300px; padding-right: 0px;"><img src="https://cdn.abc.com/files/Exclusive_Benefits_v2.png?v=1661306185" style="width: 50px; height: 50px ;" />
                    <p>Tier Benefits</p>
                    <p>Advance to next tier for more benefits and discounts.</p>
                </th>
            </section>
        </tr>
    </table>
      
</body>
</html>
```

If it keeps getting messy then the problem is in your css file. I hope it helped you :)

Comment: Hi! Since this is a code from a former developer and its on shopify, i cant seem to input any css but thank you once again :)